# Matrix 2.4 not adding rows when plus is clicked

Tags: matrix

Running Matrix 2.4 on EE 2.5

When the plus / + button on a Matrix custom field is clicked, no row is added

Nothing happens

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this before a couple of times - often just a matter of re-uploading the matrix third party theme folder.  In other cases it could be a JS conflict with another add-on, which you'd perhaps have to explore after trying the theme re-upload.